# How should we complete this laminate installation?

Tags: waterproofing, laminate-floor, laminate, underlayment, pergola

## Problem

I purchased some pergo gold underlayment and pergo waterproof laminate flooring and installed it in the kitchen with my brother. This was our first time ever installing any type of flooring, we used a jigsaw and flooring cutter. The majority of the installation came out pretty well, but there was a couple mistakes made along the way as well:

- There are 2 loose pieces of laminate that I placed at opposite corners of the kitchen. They aren't locked into the rest of the boards, how can I secure it so it doesn't move?
- The last row isn't completely locking in. Every time I attempt to tap one side using a piece within the row using a tapping block, specialized for tight spaces, another piece gets knocked out of place. What is the technique, how can i keep them in place?
- How can I make the look from one room to the other look clean? We don't have any laminate in any of the other rooms the kitchen connects to.

## Pictures

### Uneven Edge Near The Doorway

[image: uneven edge near doorway]

### Loose Laminate

[image: loose laminate]
[image: loose laminate]

### Loose Laminate #2

[image: loose laminate 2]

### Last Row

[image: last row]
[image: last row]
[image: last row]
[image: last row]

### Doorway #2

[image: doorway 2]

### Overall look and random

[image: overall]
[image: gas pipe cut]

Comment: I’m going to be rude  that is an awful job you should pull it all up. Salvage what you can and  hire a pro or watch a few hours of videos on how to install correctly

Comment: No offense taken, I uploaded several photos to provide transparency. In hindsight I shoud have hired a pro, but that is currently not in the budget. I'm just seeking guidance as to how to complete the last row, secure the two loose pieces of laminate, and making the look from room to room less clunky

Comment: Your "uneven edge near doorway" should be covered by the door threshold or a transition strip, just as an "uneven edge near wall" would be covered by trim. _Why_ do you have 2 pieces of "loose laminate"? What's stopping you from cutting pieces that have all the locking tabs/whatever that will lock those pieces into the rest of the floor?

Comment: Ideally you would remove the baseboards and threshold first, keep the gaps smaller than the baseboard width, and cover the gap with the baseboard and threshold.  In your case you have things that were installed on the baseboard that would need to be reinstalled like those outlets to make it look good. You could put smaller trim to cover the small gaps, but you have really big gaps to cover and that wouldn't work.  Glue helps with pieces that pop loose.